# Qual é a permissão correta para pastas em servidores linux em produção?

Tags: php, linux

Lendo o manual do `PHP` e alguns tutorias fiquei em dúvida sobre qual permissão deixar nas pastas após uploads de imagens. Alguns tutorias falam para deixar como 0755, outras como 0750, qual usar neste caso para a segurança da aplicação e servidor na web?

1º Exemplo:

```
chmod ("/arquivo/diretorio", 0755);
```

2º Exemplo:

```
chmod ("/arquivo/diretorio", 0750);
```

Comment: Não existe uma única maneira correta. Tem que entender como funciona e usar a que atende seu caso específico. Copiar de algum lugar é péssima idéia.

Comment: @Bacco, obrigado pela resposta, não deixando acesso total ou seja 0777 ta valendo então? Se quiser deixar uma resposta!

Comment: O problema é que depende de toda uma série de coisas no ambiente de instalação, fica complexa uma resposta cobrindo todos os casos. Depende de quem é o Owner da pasta, depende se vai querer acesso por FTP também, tem que saber quem é o usuário do webserver (que geralmente é o do PHP também), e assim por diante. Cada caso é um caso. Em geral, "quanto menos melhor" desde que a aplicação funcione. Se funcionar com 700, não precisa de 750, se precisar de 750, mas funcionar bem, não precisa de 755, mas isso é uma simplificação muito grande. Tem muito detalhe em "jogo". Melhor estudar e entender.

Comment: Entendi, valeu!

Comment: Boa, mas tinha dado uma busca antes,  veio muitas mas não essa! Mas o link me ajudou muito, obrigado mesmo. ;)

Comment: Marquei a duplicata, pq quem pesquisar essa aqui vai achar a resposta mais detalhada também, já que a resposta aceita é na linha daquela outra..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A permissão é dada da seguinte forma:

o primeiro octeto é a permissão para o usuário (dono do arquivo), o segundo octeto é para o grupo, o terceiro octeto é para todos os outros usuários. É importante você deixar a permissão mínima para usuários desconhecidos para evitar ataques no servidor.